# Removal of duplicate users on data-explorer

Tags: support, status-completed, data-explorer, duplicate-user

<sub>(I hope this is the correct place to post this - I'm not sure who "owns" the data explorer)</sub>

I originally registered on data explorer with my main open id provider and got an account (user 15). Since then, I have logged in twice using my gmail open id by mistake. Each time I was given a new account (users 40 and 965). I now have three accounts, two of which I have done nothing with and do not need.

How do I get the two duplicate accounts removed (40 and 965)?

As an aside, is there a plan to allow more than one open id per account the same as the SOFU sites do?

Comment: This is the right place to post questions about Data Explorer. It was originally created independently by [Sam Saffron](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron) but is now in cooperation with the Stack Overflow peops.

Comment: @ccomet: I knew Sam was behind it, but now its url has changed to odata.sta... I wasn't sure who was the "responsible person".

Comment: Ah, I see. Actualy, he seems to even have the power to mark [status-completed] here on Meta without the diamond.

Comment: @adrian: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54153/why-are-there-two-sofu-data-sites

Comment: @ccomet: He's a regular user like you or I. `[status-completed]` gets added quickly by observant mods or through flagging.

Comment: @Jon http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/53493/revisions among many others. I presume this was to simply speed up the tagging process since there are a *lot* of Data Explorer questions and he addresses them fairly quickly.

Comment: If someone could point him this way it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: @ccomet: Wow. Never saw that before. Thanks.

Comment: @Jon @ccomet ... for the record, waffles is not yet an admin and the history shenanigans are due to some database history wizardry and/or tag renaming done by admins. I started tagging stuff `status-completeded` and the admins renamed the tags.   As for the history of SEDE, Stack Overflow has always been behind it from get go. As for waffles becoming an admin, this may happen sometime in the future.

Comment: @waffles: Ahhhhh that makes sense. I didn't think Jeff had implemented that kind of permission system.

Comment: @ccomet: Comment ping.

Comment: @waffles So Jeff did yet more of his global rewrite of history. It makes more sense than the permissions, yeah... also explains that one of those posts questioned you using "status-completeded" but the history showed no sign of that ever happening. It's temporal anomalies like this that explain why we need more totally rad programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adrian, I just merged your accounts and another 10 or so dupe accounts I came by.

I am also setting up a permanent redirect for the old cloudexchange url which is causing a lot of these account so show up.

As it stands the DB supports multiple open ids per account, but there is not UI to associate them, I sort it out with `spMergeUserBasedOnEmail` which is far from ideal.

For the time beings I am trying to run:

```
select email, count(*) from Users 
where len(isnull(email, '')) > 0
group by email
having count(*) > 1
```

Once a week or so to catch the accounts and then will run a merge.

As soon as SEDE goes open source I will welcome a patch that sorts out this mess and brings stuff inline with SO.

I think it makes sense to post a separate feature request for to allow for multiple open ids per account, it is totally `status-approved`