# The hash of my Email address is on my data explorer profile page (somewhere)

Tags: support, data-explorer

I did [a google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cad89a877102a31fd4642bfd88e3e9a6&oq=cad89a877102a31fd4642bfd88e3e9a6&aqs=chrome..69i57.128j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for the md5 hash of my email address:

```
cad89a877102a31fd4642bfd88e3e9a6
```

Top result is [my profile page on the data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/15277/timtjtim?order_by=recent&page=1).

Comment: [No it's not](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n56pp.png).

Answer (score 8):

It's being used for [your gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cad89a877102a31fd4642bfd88e3e9a6?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG), since that's how Gravatar works.

Ideally it should be possible disable that if you want to (but I'm guessing you don't, since you use Gravatar here too), it's on the todo-list. You could remove the email field value, but until [another issue is fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261181/two-sede-accounts-please-fix-and-how-do-i-avoid-this)* Google logins are tied to the value of that field, so if you use Google to login that would stop working.

<sub>*I've submitted a PR, but it hasn't been deployed, but apparently somewhere along the lines it picked up some conflicts, so I'll see if I can get those fixed and have someone look at it</sub>